# scala-pact provider verification using specific service url

Tags: scala, pact

I'm trying to perform provider verification using scala-pact implementation. My dockerized service under test is located at `http://localhost:9999/my_test_label/my_service`. There is

`def runVerificationAgainst[F[_]](protocol: String, host: String, port: Int, clientTimeout: Duration)`

function provided by scala-test bu I'm unable to provide such url as mine. The problem is `my_test_label` needed by other tests (or anything between port number and service url). The only thing I can do is to invoke the verifier as follow:
`runVerificationAgainst("http", "localhost", 9999, 10.seconds)`
which ends with verifying the `http://localhost:9999/my_service` (`my_service` is provided from the pact.json file).

The only workarounds I found is to remove the `my_test_label` from the dockerized service (which is hard because of dependencies) or to capture and modify the pact.json file before the verification (which is not a good practise). Is it possible to provide such url into the scala-pact verifier or I need to use pact CLI to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 0):

This question is more about the application design.

- The contract must always be declared with full path, i.e. **anything after the port**. If it doesn't, you bring confusion against the expectations from the URL at any environment this app will be located.
- The server application should always be customizable for the base path, i.e. declare in properties. If so, you're capable implement any test against any base path.

Particular advice here: adjust the pact on the consumer side to the side of the target path, I assume it is `/my_test_label/my_service`